# I want to add bootstrap into the angular but it showing me error help me in solving this

Tags: angular

I am adding bootstrap by using this command -->ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap but it throwing me error like this --> A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\WIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-08T07_06_22_607Z-debug-0.log

plss help me how to resolve this issue

I tried this command ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap and i am expecting it to add bootstrap on angular

Comment: open the indicate file using an editor and tell us what say

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force

this will add files regardless of version mismatch.

You can try: ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force --verbose

--verbose will display additional details about internal operations during execution. So you can get more info on whats the issue.